# Вывод масива Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Всем доброго времени суток....есть стандартный Angular контроллер

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

    phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.name = "";
      $scope.mod = "";
      $scope.cena = "";
      $scope.maysters = [];
      $scope.addToList = function() {
        this.maysters.push({
          name: this.name,
          mod: this.mod,
          cena: this.cena
        })
      }
    });
```

Масив mayster содержит архив заказов...функция AddToList додает заказ в архив

1.Как мне позволить администратору  добавлять новый масив с архивом и функцию к нему ( без использования кода, через input ) ?

2.Как выводить на екран созданый масив ?

Comment: Вопросы не очень понятны. Поясните пожалуйста, что значит *динамически добавлять новый масив с архивом и функцию к нему*?

Comment: @stepan через инмут добавить в масив елемент а потом вывесьт его на екран событием on-click или дерективой ng-click...может подскажете где можно поискать инфу по етой теме , ибо я немогу правильно вопрос поставить в гугле

Comment: офтопик: Вы в скайпе то ответьте) онтопик: Ищите в гугле директивы `ng-click` и `ng-repeat`.